# How to extract a solution

Tags: equation-solving

Is there any way to get the actual number from this?

```
NSolve[x^2 - 5 y^2 == 1, {x, y}, Integers][[1]][[1]]
```

instead of

```
x -> ConditionalExpression[  1/2 (-(9 - 4 Sqrt[5])^C[1] - (9 + 4 Sqrt[5])^C[1]),  C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]
```

and more importantly, is there any way to get the coefficient of the square root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the parameter `C[1]` so that the condition becomes true. For instance

```
sol = {x, y} /. NSolve[x^2 - 5 y^2 == 1, {x, y}, Integers] /. C[1] :> 3
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and to extract the coefficients of the sqare-roots

```
Cases[sol[[1, 1]], coeff_*Sqrt[__] :> coeff, Infinity]
```

Comment: whoa! :D that's awesome XD thanks!
How about the first term? (9) How could I get to that?
Nm, I guess having C[1]=1 does that >.>